# Perl: How to find total number of rows in a sqlite database without using max(rowid)?

Tags: perl, sqlite

I wanted to find out Number of Rows in a SQLITE database Table, i know that i can query using `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLENAME;`
but i wanted to get the count using the perl code and store it into a variable? can i use the below code

```
my $stmt = qq(SELECT COUNT(*) AS $NUMBEROFROWS FROM TABLENAME)
$rv = $dbh->do($stmt);
```

OR

```
my $stmt = qq(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLENAME
              $NUMBEROFROWS = COUNT(*)      );
$rv = $dbh->do($stmt);
```

Please suggest me how to count number of rows in SQLITE database table and store the value into a variable?

TIA

Comment: GOT SOLVED $count = $dbh->selectrow_array("
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM INFORMATION
");
print "$count \n";

Comment: Using _array and populating a scalar seems confusing.

Comment: Please create an answer, in order to get this out of the unanswered questions list.

Comment: @choroba, `selectrow_array` in scalar context is fine when there's a single column because "the driver will return the value of the first column or the last".

Answer (score 6):

Perl variables aren't part of the SQL, you get the number from the database and populate the variable in Perl:

```
my ($count) = $dbh->selectrow_array('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information');
print "$count\n";
```